# When should specific constructors be implemented?

Tags: c++, class, constructor

If I have different attributes in my class, for example following code:

```
class Position
{
    double latitude;
    double longitude;
    double altitude;

    PosixTime time;
};
```

So we say this is the class I want to construct, where `time` is (at current time of development) always the **current time**. I currently don't use any other times, it's always the creation time. Should I still implement a constructor with a time parameter? Maybe it's used later or by another developer? Summarized there two options:

1. Writing only 2 constructors:

   ```
   Position()
   : latitude(0)
   , longitude(0)
   , alitutde(0)
   , time(PosixCurrentTime()) {}

   Position(double lat, double lon, double alt)
   : latitude(lat)
   , longitude(lon)
   , alitutde(alt)
   , time(PosixCurrentTime()) {}
   ```
2. Writing 3 constructors (both from top and the following):

   ```
   Position(double lat, double lon, double alt, PosixTime t)
   : latitude(lat)
   , longitude(lon)
   , alitutde(alt)
   , time(t) {}
   ```

Comment: Well, if time could be specified, you could use constructor 3 and 1 with `PosixCurrentTime()`as default argument. This could be a good idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whether you provide a constructor that allows setting the `time` to some arbitrary value or not is a design decision you should make depending on the semantics of the class. Think of future use cases, and whether that functionality would make sense. If you do decide on that, you could merge constructors 2 and 3 into a single one.

```
Position(double lat, double lon, double alt, PosixTime t = PosixCurrentTime())
: latitude(lat)
, longitude(lon)
, alitutde(alt)
, time(t) {}
```

And if your compiler supports C++11, define the class as

```
class Position
{
    double latitude = 0;
    double longitude = 0;
    double altitude = 0;

    PosixTime time = PosixCurrentTime();

public:
    Position() = default;
    Position(double lat, double lon, double alt, PosixTime t = PosixCurrentTime())
    : latitude(lat)
    , longitude(lon)
    , alitutde(alt)
    , time(t) {}
};
```

Answer (score 2):

You only need one constructor, with default values for its parameters.

```
Position(double lat = 0, double lon = 0, double alt = 0, PosixTime t = get_current_time())
  : latitude(lat), longitude(lon), alitutde(alt), time(t) 
{
}
```

Notice that in this example `get_current_time()` is a placeholder for the function that returns you the current time.

Comment: C++11 simplifies this case; `= 0;` can be written in the class definition for all the doubles, freeing the constructor to just take the optional time

Comment: @MattMcNabb Which doesn't help much; he wants to be able to specify the values.

Answer (score 0):

If time is (at current time of development) **ALWAYS** the current time, then you can declare only a get method:

```
class Position {
public:
  static Posixtime getCurrentTime() const;
private:
    double latitude;
    double longitude;
    double altitude;
};
```

This is an option, otherwise you should have only one constructor with all default values:

```
class Position {
public:
  Position(const double& = 0, const double& = 0, const double& = 0, const PosixTime& = getCurrentTime())
};

Position::Position(const double& lat, const double& lon, const double& alt, const PosixTime& t) : 
    latitude(lat),
    longitude(lon),
    altitude(alt),
    time(t) {
}
```

Comment: It's the current time of constructing the class, not the time when getting some attributes. By the way, why are you make the method `static`?

Comment: because I've understand "current time" as "time in this moment". So this value don't change between instances but it is the same for all, isn't it? Instead, if is the time when you create object Position, I'm wrong.

Comment: if they were the same then this makes absolutly sense. But unfortunately they are not. Each class has a different time. Thanks for making that `static` thing clear to me :)